# Call to database from Javascript in aspx page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have a gridview using devexpress tools that is populated on page load. When I select a row I have button that will allow me to edit the information in that row by popping up an edit box that allows me to change the information. The issue I am having is when they click that button the data that was behind the gridivew could have changed so I want to be able to query the database again (using some parameters from the selected row) when that edit button is clicked.

Here is the query that is ran when the 'edit' button is clicked.

function ShowPopupEditInventory() {

```
        $.when(getFocusedInventory()).then(function (x) {
            popupControlEditInventory.Show();
        });

        function getFocusedInventory(s, e) {
            grid.GetRowValues(grid.GetFocusedRowIndex(), 'StorageLocation;LP;Sku_Alpha;LotCode;ExpirationDate;FIFOReferenceDate;ManufactureDate;InventoryStatus;SellableUnitQuantity;ReceiveDate;InventoryDetailID;Area', getFocusedInventoryValues);
        }

        function getFocusedInventoryValues(values) {
            var fStorageLocation = values[0];
            var fLP = values[1];
            var fSku_Alpha = values[2];
            var fLotCode = values[3];
            var fExpirationDate = values[4];
            var fFIFOReferenceDate = values[5];
            var fManufactureDate = values[6];
            var fInventoryStatus = values[7];
            var fSellableUnitQuantity = values[8];
            var fReceiveDate = values[9];
            var fInventoryDetailID = values[10];
            var fArea = values[11];


            editInventoryStorageLocation.SetText(fStorageLocation);
            editInventoryLP.SetText(fLP);
            editInventoryItem.SetText(fSku_Alpha);
            editInventoryQty_OldValue.SetText(fSellableUnitQuantity);
            editInventorySts_OldValue.SetText(fInventoryStatus);
            editInventoryLot_OldValue.SetText(fLotCode);
            txtEditInventoryLot.SetText(fLotCode);
            $(".editInventoryLot").val(fLotCode);

            editInventoryStatus.SetValue(fInventoryStatus)
            editInventoryUnitQuantity.SetText(fSellableUnitQuantity);
            editInventoryDTL_No.SetText(fInventoryDetailID);
            editInventoryNotes.SetText('');
            $(".editInventoryAdjustmentCode").prop("selectedIndex", 0);
            editInventoryArea.SetText(fArea);


            editInventoryLot.Focus();

            btnOKEditInventory.SetEnabled(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear.... when the page load it loads an entire gridview worth of data.... when I click edit on the row I load all the information into an edit PopUp. This is done with javascript. What I am wanting to do is take a few values from that row, which I already have, and make a call back to the database to get the latest SellableUnitQuantity when that button is clicked and before it is loaded into the popup.

Comment: I'm still not hearing a question in there....

Comment: How do I make a callback to the database from the javascript code? I want to make a call back and query a database and update the fSellableUnitQuantity above instead of pulling it from the row.

Comment: That's a big question there. There are lots of ways to go about it. You could make an AJAX call, make a web socket call etc. The JavaScript can't directly hit the database, all it can do is communicate via HTTP back to the web server, which can then make the appropriate calls to the database. Probably best for you to learn about AJAX and how to expose server side endpoints (probably via [Web API](https://www.asp.net/web-api)) for the JavaScript to talk to.

Comment: Read up on how to use ajax

Comment: Is there anything I should specifically look into? I'm basically wanting to access a database server and run a query in a specific database (this DB Name Changes) and return a value using parameters that I already have in the Javascript.